# how to get generated SQL for stored procedure call through Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am currently building a custom front-end for an application mainly based on SQL Server stored application. In this context, I want to get the SQL generated by Entity Framework 6 when calling a stored procedure. I found how to do it with a query, by calling ObjectQuery.ToTraceString(), but I can't do the same on a call to a stored proc that returns an int.
Does anyone know how to proceed?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Ced.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server Profiler (part of SQL Server, Performance Tools.  It is not part of VStudio or C#).  It can trace all communications with a DB.  Have it log to a local file (on your HDD). There might be a lot of traffic, so you will probably want to filter, so you only trace your SP.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal and sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately, it won't fit my needs as I need to get the information programmatically, within my application, for it to be displayed to users and potentially edited.